# Intellij "Find Action" shortcut / hotkey not working on Windows

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

On Windows, the shortcut `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `A` to open the Find Action popup is not working. I've tried re-installing the whole IntelliJ IDE already but the issue still persists, anyone who has experienced this issue?

I'm using version 2019.2 since this is my Ultimate license.

What could be the work around for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an exact idea what has happened. But there may be some shortcut *conflicts*.
As an example, same shortcut keys will do different jobs based on the focus location. As an example my **Ctrl + D** key combination do lot of jobs as shown below,

[image: intelij idea ctrl + d]

---

You can find the shortcut actions assigned to **Ctrl + Shift + A**, by going to *Settings > Keymap*, and with using *Find Actions by Shortcut* as shown below;

[image]

---

[image]

Then you can clarify actions assigned for your **Ctrl + Shift + A**.